# Highlight variables/functions in commens of all prog-modes

Tags: font-lock, prog-mode

In `lisp-mode`, strings inside comments that are encapsulated by `' are highlighted with `font-lock-constant-face`.

How can I make all prog-mode-derived modes do that by default?

Comment: Kind of a meta-answer: propose to the Emacs devs that they make this feature of elisp-mode an independent minor mode that can be activated in any prog-mode derivative.

Comment: You could easily do that yourself. There are many packages that provide font-lock rules as minor modes, e.g. https://github.com/Lindydancer/lisp-extra-font-lock/blob/master/lisp-extra-font-lock.el and https://github.com/Lindydancer/preproc-font-lock/blob/master/preproc-font-lock.el